# Остановить выполнение остальных тестов, если не прошла проверка в предыдущем

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, nunit

Добрый вечер. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно остановить выполнение тестов NUnit, если в определенном тесте не пройдена проверка? Самое главное, что не после каждого фейла, а именно после определенного, после которого тестирование не имеет смысла.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Если я правильно проинтерпретировал вторую фразу, то вы хотите реализовать такую логику:

> Останови все тесты, которые уже выполняются в нескольких других потоках, потому что у меня тут что-то пошло не так.

- Ни `NUnit`, ни `xUnit`, как мне известно, такого не позволяют, да и, вообще говоря, это неправильный подход к задаче, поскольку механизм и порядок запуска тестов может быть совершенно недетерминированным и может вообще не использовать какой-либо привычный вам тест-раннер.
- Решите вашу задачу следующим образом: **вынесите вашу проверку в `[SetUp]`.** Если эта проверка (которая, по сути, имеет семантику `precondition`) не будет пройдена, то тест сразу же сфейлится и все. В случае, если вычисление этого условия может занимать длительное время, используйте для нее какой-нибудь кастомный `lazy` геттер и просто закэшируйте результат.

---

- В [**этом треде**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657767/how-to-make-nunit-stop-executing-tests-on-first-failure) предлагается подход с использованием `Thread.Abort()`, однако предложенное там решение является костылем, корректно не для всех случаев и *(на мой взгляд)* не имеет смысла при правильной логической организации тестов.

  ```
  [Test]
  public void AbortingTest()
  {
      AsСertain(() => Assert.AreEqual(0, 1));
  }

  private static void AsCertain(Action condition)
  {
      try
      {
          condition.Invoke();
      }
      catch (AssertionException assertionException)
      {
          Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Возьмите за основу MinUnit и допилите - http://www.jera.com/techinfo/jtns/jtn002.html

Как я понимаю, достаточно в третьей строке заменить return message на puts(message)

Тогда при неправильном ассерте будет прервано не всё тестирование, а только текущий тест. Тесты будут выполнены все. Сгруппируйте ассерты, которые "не имеют смысла", в один тест, расположив их сразу после того ассерта, который их "обессмысливает". That's all, folks!